# ERROR Caused by: android.app.SuperNotCalledException:

Tags: android

I have a ftp client normally sends the files, but when I press menu, or get a call on your phone, it does not send in the background and closes the application. is this normal? I send a file, and when you're almost done someone calls me and clears my upload should I start over?

thank you.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.informacoes);
    assunto     = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tf_assunto);
    comentario  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tf_comentario);
    onde        = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tf_onde);
    if(caminhoArquivo != null){
        arquivo = new File(caminhoArquivo);
    }
    else{
        finish();
    }
    enviar();
    sair();

    enviarSegundoPlano = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            nomeArquivo = arquivo.getName();
            return null;
        }
    };
    enviarSegundoPlano.execute();
}

    private void enviarArquivo(final File arquivo){
    Tarefa tarefa = new Tarefa(mProgressDialog){
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try{
                //ftp.abort();
                if(conecta(usuario, senha, host)){
                    State wifi = Principal.conexao.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();
                    final String subPasta = txAssunto;
                    FileChannel fileChannelEntrada = new RandomAccessFile(arquivo, "r").getChannel();
                    ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(pasta);
                    ftp.mkd(subPasta);
                    ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(subPasta);
                    ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                    if(wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED){
                        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    }
                    WritableByteChannel saida = Channels.newChannel(ftp.storeFileStream(arquivo.getName()));
                    //ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16384);
                    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(90);
                    byteBuffer.clear();
                    while(fileChannelEntrada.read(byteBuffer) != -1){
                        byteBuffer.flip();
                        saida.write(byteBuffer);
                        byteBuffer.clear();
                        publishProgress(getPorcentagem(fileChannelEntrada.size(), fileChannelEntrada.position()));
                        if(fileChannelEntrada.read(byteBuffer) > 0 && fileChannelEntrada.read(byteBuffer) < 100){
                            resposta = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                resposta = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            enviarArquivo(arquivoTXT, true);
            if(resposta){
                try{
                    new Thread(){
                        public void run(){
                            try{
                                Email email = new Email(Principal.emailUsuario, txAssunto, txOnde, txComentario);
                                email.enviarEmail();
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }.start();
                    mostrarTextoTela("Enviado com Sucesso!");
                }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
            else{
                mostrarTextoTela("Erro ao Enviar");
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            finish();
        }
    };
    tarefa.execute();
}
```

**Logcat**

```
01-09 07:09:26.789: D/dalvikvm(21014): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 57K, 48% free 2808K/5379K, external 511K/517K, paused 195ms
01-09 07:10:09.140: D/dalvikvm(21534): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 56K, 48% free 2803K/5379K, external 511K/517K, paused 38ms
01-09 07:10:24.281: D/dalvikvm(21534): GC_CONCURRENT freed 215K, 47% free 3026K/5639K, external 816K/996K, paused 4ms+3ms
01-09 07:12:01.234: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(21534): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-09 07:12:07.101: W/dalvikvm(22169): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
01-09 07:12:07.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22169): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-09 07:12:07.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22169): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-09 07:12:07.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22169):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
01-09 07:12:07.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22169):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
01-09 07:12:07.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22169):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
01-09 07:12:07.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22169):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
01-09 07:12:07.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22169):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-09 07:12:07.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22169):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-09 07:12:07.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22169):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-09 07:12:07.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22169):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-09 07:12:07.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22169): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 07:12:07.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22169):    at br.com.marcio.Informacoes$1.doInBackground(Informacoes.java:75)
01-09 07:12:07.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22169):    at br.com.marcio.Informacoes$1.doInBackground(Informacoes.java:1)
01-09 07:12:07.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22169):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-09 07:12:07.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22169):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
01-09 07:12:07.109: E/AndroidRuntime(22169):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Post your Logacat.As u  title this question abour Error occurs but u had not define the situation when the error occurs. please explain your question bit more.

Comment: Do you have `onPause` or `OnResume` etc where you haven;t called `super.pause()` or `super.onResume` ?

Comment: please check yours lifecycle methods carefully.

Comment: excuse, and I'm new in this android world, put the logcat, thank you for your attention

Comment: NPE in `doInBackground()` of the first anon asynctask - likely `arquivo` is `null`.

Comment: Shobhit Puri, I'm not overriding the onPause and onResume methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enviarSegundoPlano = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      if(arquivo!=null)
        nomeArquivo = arquivo.getName();
      else{
        Log.d("LOG_APP", "arquivo null");
        // ...
      }
        return null;
    }
};
enviarSegundoPlano.execute();
```

Handle situations when arkuivo is null